# SQL like with multiple characters

Tags: sql, db2, sql-like

I'm trying to perform some selects in DB2 SQL, using the LIKE command, specifically looking for values that start with certain multiple digits. I thought I was using the expression correctly, but I keep getting syntax errors and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
Right now I've been trying:

```
Select ID, NAME
From Table1
Where ID LIKE '888%'
Or ID LIKE '999%';
```

Am I just using the wrong SQL for the environment? (This is polling DB2 for Zo/s) LIKE doesn't seem to work when I just try a single 8% or 9% either.

I appreciate any shared experience, thank you!

Comment: the id data type is number or char ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure the id is not a number and if is a number then  cast as char

```
Select ID, NAME
From Table1
Where cast(ID as char(10)) LIKE '888%'
 Or cast(ID as char(10)) LIKE '999%';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data type is number then you can try the following

```
Select ID, NAME
From Table1
Where to_char(ID) LIKE '888%'
Or to_char(ID) LIKE '999%';
```